# array list .get not working in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am making a binary to denary converter in java. I have looked online and its seems clear that to get an element from an array list in java is with .get. But when I use this I get an error saying "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable".
Here are the relevant bits of my code

```
ArrayList binarynew = new ArrayList();

int finished = 0;
int[] numbers = {128,64,32,16,8,4,2,1};
for (int k = 0; k<7; k++){
    if (binarynew.get(k) = '1'){
        finished = finished + numbers[k];
    }
}
System.out.println(finished);
```

Comment: `binarynew` doed not have anything. What do you expect `get()` to return?

Comment: Are you trying to compare to '1' or assign '1'?

Comment: plz read how to write `if` clause!

Answer (score 0):

To evaluate for equality in Java you have to use `==`, not `=`, which is used to assign values to variables So replace:

```
if (binarynew.get(k) = '1')
```

by:

```
if (binarynew.get(k) == '1')
```

Note that you have to be careful when using `==` with reference variables, it depends what type of `Arraylist` it is. Consider using `equals()` if it applies.

Comment: that would lead to an IndexOutOfBoundsException since the ArrayList is empty

Comment: @Eran you're right, but I'm assuming that it's not empty. This looks like pseudocode, and the error he's describing is not due to out of bounds

Comment: thank you. i have learnt this and know it from other proggraming but it just didnt come to mind. thanks for answering so qiuckly

Answer (score 0):

The error is obviously due to assignment. Use '==' instead to '='.

And the code would throw IndexOutOfBound exception also as the List is empty.
Do this instead :

```
List<Integer> binarynew = Arrays.asList(128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1);
    int finished = 0;
    int[] numbers = {128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1};
    for (int k = 0; k <= 7; k++) {
        if (binarynew.get(k) == 1) {
            finished = finished + numbers[k];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(finished);
```